# Django user login session not accessible when I try to fetch it from my React frontend

Tags: reactjs, django

I have a django app running. I have created a login_status view under my API that returns JSON:true/false if I am logged in or not.

When I load this in my browser it works fine.
When my React app tries to fetch this same page, Django ALWAYS returns false. Somehow my login session is invisible. How do I fix this?

Note: My React app & Django app are running on two different ports. I have enabled CORS by installing django-cors-headers.

I am not using the React REST Framework, just plain Django.

here is my front end code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Modal from 'react-modal'
import Vim from './Vim';
import './Main.css';
import './modal.css';
Modal.setAppElement('#root')

function Main():JSX.Element { 

  const [postId,updatePostId] = useState<number|null>(null)
  const [content, updateContent] = useState<string>('default text');
  const [auth, updateAuth] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [authModalIsOpen, setAuthModal] = useState(false)
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'

  function openAuthModal(){ setAuthModal(true) }
  function closeAuthModal(){
    if(auth){ setAuthModal(false) }
  }

  function get_api(path:string){
    return fetch(apiUrl+path)
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(result=>result)
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(postId){

      // Detect change in PostID & go download it.
      // Ignore if we are coming from null->number
      fetch(apiUrl+'get_post/'+postId)
      .then(res=>res.json())
    }
  },[postId])

  useEffect(()=>{
    // if auth is false, check if this is true on API end.
    if(!auth){
      let status = get_api('login_status')
      status.then(result=>{
        console.log(result.auth)
        if(result.auth){
          console.log('just logged him in')
        } else {
          console.log('open modal')
          openAuthModal()
        } 
      })
    } else{
      closeAuthModal()
    }
  },[auth])

  function loadPost(pid:number):string|null{
    // fetch from API, load post content
    console.log('I can access:'+postId)
    return null;
  }
  
  function backLinks():JSX.Element{
    
    return(
      <div className="backlinks">
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  function sendLogin(){
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: username,
        password: password
      })
    }
    return fetch(apiUrl+'login', requestOptions)
      .then(response=>response.json())
  }

  return (
    <div className='main'>
      <Vim key={postId} content={content} />

      <Modal
        isOpen={authModalIsOpen}
        onRequestClose={closeAuthModal}
        className='Modal'
        overlayClassName='Overlay'
        >
        <form onSubmit={(e)=>{
          e.preventDefault()
          console.log(username)
          sendLogin().then((data)=>{
            if(data.auth){
              updateAuth(true)
            }
          })
        }}>
            <input name='username' onChange={(e)=>{
              setUsername(e.target.value)
            }}/>
            <input type="password" name='password' onChange={(e)=>{
              setPassword(e.target.value)
            }}/>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
          </form>
        </Modal> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default Main
```

Here is my code from django

```
@require_login
def login_status(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.user.id)
    return JsonResponse({'auth':True})
```

```
def require_login(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'auth':False})
    wrap.__doc__ =  function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__= function.__name__
    return wrap
```

And settings...

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ur#1ppk98a$ujlytxx9ys&r4)9o9o2+iiss^f_a)(=l@1#c=s8'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'notes',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'vnote.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'vnote.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'notes.User'


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Comment: Are you using session or token based authentication ? DRF or plain Django ? Can you show us the front & backend code used for authenticate the user ?

Comment: Updated with code. I'm using plain django. Session based. I would like to avoid using the django-rest-framework, as I don't want to have to learn aother framework. Is this the only way?

Comment: Token auth (JWT precisely) would be much easier in a situation where you run react and django as 2 different services. Anyway, for what you're trying to do you'd need to manually send the session key in the cookie from the frontend just as Django expects it (good luck for that).  DRF would make it easier, not just for auth, but also later when you need to perform CRUD operations. It's not so much work learning it when you already know Django tbh, just getting familiar with serializer. Here you're kinda reinventing the wheel...